# Can't figure out Python scraping code issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using python/bs to scrape this site: https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html

There's two annoying issues that I can't figure out:

1. It always includes *'Resolution Agreements,/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html'* as the first entry of the CSV.
2. The actual first entry of the site is never included. In this case, *"HHS’ Office for Civil Rights Settles Malicious Insider Cybersecurity Investigation for $4.75 Million"*

Any suggestions?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# URL of the page to scrape
url = "https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all <a> tags containing the links
links = soup.find_all('a')

# Create and open a CSV file in write mode
with open('hipaa_links.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Create a CSV writer object
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'URL'])

    # Iterate over each link
    for link in links:
        # Extract link URL
        link_url = link.get('href')

        # Extract link title
        link_title = link.text.strip()

        # Check if the link is related to "Resolution Agreements" or subsequent ones and if link text and URL are not empty
        if link_url and link_title and "/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/" in link_url:
            # Write the link title and URL to the CSV file
            writer.writerow([link_title, link_url])

print("Data has been written to hipaa_links.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Resolution Agreements' link is from the left side-bar/nav, and the first link (the HHS Office .. settles...) goes to an `/about/news/` page.

I'd suggest you filter your search down to the innermost `l-content` div, and remove the filter on link destination:

```py
content_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='l-content')
content_div = content_divs[-1]
links = content_div.find_all('a')
...
        if link_url and link_title:
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Issue is that you are not that specific with your selection, try to focus the `<a>` you really like to scrape - Using [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) you can stil filter your results. Followoing will just select the `<a>` from the link list, thats `href` meets your statement:

   ```
   soup.select('section.usa-section ul a[href*="hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements"]')
   ```
2. Issue here is that the first link do not fit your statement:

   https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2024/02/06/hhs-office-civil-rights-settles-malicious-insider-cybersecurity-investigation.html

   Do not contain:

   ```
   "/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/"
   ```

   That is the reason why int never show up.

###### Example based on your code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# URL of the page to scrape
url = "https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements/index.html"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all <a> tags containing the links
links = soup.select('section.usa-section ul a[href*="hipaa/for-professionals/compliance-enforcement/agreements"]')

# Create and open a CSV file in write mode
with open('hipaa_links.csv', mode='w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Create a CSV writer object
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write the header row
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'URL'])

    # Iterate over each link
    for link in links:
        # Extract link URL
        link_url = link.get('href')

        # Extract link title
        link_title = link.text.strip()
        writer.writerow([link_title, link_url])

print("Data has been written to hipaa_links.csv")
```